# Can I restore lost photos fron backup?

Tags: iphone, backup

I have an iPhone 4,16G.

I had a ringtone issue and Apple support did a software reboot.

Before starting, a phone backup was done. All apps are back as well as phone contacts. However, all my photos are missing.

Can these be restored?

Comment: Did you restore the backup after doing the software reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Photos and Videos in the camera roll (not photo stream) are indeed in the backup file. I would copy the backup file to a second location so that you can have a backup of it. There are also tools that allow you to examine the contents of a iPhone backup. http://addpod.com/juicephone

Try juicephone first and if need be you can restore your phone to the backup temporarily.